# How do you make labels visible again once their visibility is set to false?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, user-controls

In asp.net webforms I have a UserControl with a code-behind file (shown below).

The UserControl has two `<asp:Label>` nodes in it that I am attempting to use as steps in a form.

The problem is that when I get to "Step2" and click `Cancel`, "Step1" does not re-display, despite the fact that I am setting its `Visible` property to true.

What am I doing wrong? Or is there a better way to do this?

#### UserControl

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
CodeFile="MyUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="_MyUserControl" %>

<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblStep1" Visible="true">
    <fieldset>
        <p>Some initial text here</p>
        <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" ID="cmdSubmit" Text="Submit" />
    </fieldset>
</asp:Label>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblStep2" Visible="false">
    <p>Some text here</p>
    <div>
        <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" ID="cmdRequest" Text="Send The Request" />&nbsp;
        <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn" ID="cmdCancel" Text="Cancel" />
    </div>
</asp:Label>
```

#### Code-behind

```
public partial class _MyUserControl : UserControl
{

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmdCancel.Click  += new EventHandler(cmdCancel_Click);
        cmdSubmit.Click  += new EventHandler(cmdSubmit_Click);
    }

    public void cmdSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblStep1.Visible = false;
        lblStep2.Visible = true;
    }

    public void cmdCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // return to the previous step
        lblStep1.Visible = true;
        lblStep2.Visible = false;
    }
```

}

Comment: Why do you put the buttons inside the label?

Comment: Ha! I had assumed (without looking at the documentation) that the label was a generic container! I should have known better.

Comment: yup :) see the answer from Rahul. This should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not doing anything with those `labels` and that's a wrong idea to have buttons defined inside label control. Looks like you are trying to use label as container control. Rather use a `<div>` element/tag as container and try. It should work.

```
<div runat="server" ID="lblStep1" Visible="true">
    <fieldset>
        <p>Some initial text here</p>
        <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" ID="cmdSubmit" Text="Submit" />
    </fieldset>
</div>
<div runat="server" ID="lblStep2" Visible="false">
    <p>Some text here</p>
    <div>
        <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" ID="cmdRequest" Text="Send The Request" />&nbsp;
        <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn" ID="cmdCancel" Text="Cancel" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked great! Thanks @Rahul!